# Array retorna valor errado em java

Tags: java, array, string, arquivo, for

Estou com uma dúvida sobre um trabalho de faculdade. Eu consigo ler com números, retirar o ";" e passar os valores para o array durante a leitura do arquivo. Porém, quando tento acessar uma posição do array fora da leitura do arquivo, ele não retorna o valor que tenho no arquivo e sim um outro valor. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

ARQUIVO QUE LEIO

```
10
1;1;1
2;2;3;2;150;20
3;3;3;1;100;10
4;4;3;4;350;30
5;5;3;1;100;10
6;6;3;2;150;20
7;7;3;3;100;10
8;8;3;5;500;10
9;9;2
10;10;3;1;100;10
```

SAÍDA DO PROGRAMA

```
10
1
1
1
2
2
3
2
150
20
```

e assim por diante ...

Se eu quero ler o número 2 que está na 5ª posição da saída, eu faço:

```
 System.out.println(array[4]);
```

e ao invés de retornar o número 2 ele retorna o 100.

MEU CÓDIGO

```
package jogo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Tabuleiro {

private static BufferedReader br;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] array = null;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/overwatch/tabuleiro1.txt"));
            String linha = br.readLine();

            while(linha!=null){
                array = linha.split(";");
                linha = br.readLine();

                for(int i=0; i < array.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                }
            }   
            br.close();

            //imprimindo o 3 valor que está no array
            System.out.println(array[4]);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste código aqui:

```
while(linha!=null){
    array = linha.split(";");

 ...
}
```

Você está sobrescrevendo o array a cada iteração no while.
No final seu array só estará com os valores da última linha do arquivo (**"10;10;3;1;100;10"**) onde a posição 4 realmente é o valor 100. Seu código está exibindo na tela todos valores de cada linha do arquivo, mas armazenando no array somente a última linha lida.
Você poderia usar um ArrayList para armazenar os valores assim:

```
    public class Tabuleiro {

    private static BufferedReader br;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/overwatch/tabuleiro1.txt"));
            String linha = br.readLine();

            while (linha != null) {
                String[] lineValues = linha.split(";");
                linha = br.readLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < lineValues.length; i++) {
                    array.add(lineValues[i]);
                    System.out.println(lineValues[i]);
                }
            }
            br.close();

            // imprimindo o 3 valor que está no array
            System.out.println(array.get(4));

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom que teve que mudar pouca coisa no meu código... obrigada pela explicação e solução :)

Answer (score 0):

Você não está guardando no array cada linha que vc lê.
Uma proposta é fazer assim:

```
 public static List<String> leExibeArquivo(String arquivo) {
        String s, temp;            
        //   HashSet<String> valores = new HashSet<>();//ArrayList antes
        List<String> valores = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("O arquivo aberto é: " + arquivo);
        System.out.println("Exibindo arquivo:");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(arquivo))) {
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
                valores.add(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("Erro de E/S " + exc);
        }

        return valores;
    }
```

Você chamaria o método assim:

```
 List<String> linhas = new ArrayList<String>();
            String arquivo = "/home/overwatch/tabuleiro1.txt";
            linhas = leExibeArquivo(arquivo);//recebe o arquivo em um ArrayList, cada posição uma linha
            //o retorno do método leExibeArquivo(String) é um ArrayList
```

E em seguida poderia converter para um array normal da seguinte forma:

```
Object vetorLinhas[] = linhas.toArray();    //converte o ArrayList com as linhas para um array.

        System.out.println("Exibe o vetor com as linhas:"); //cada linha em um aposição do vetor - vai ser usado para comparar
        for (int i = 0; i < vetorLinhas.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("linhas[%d]= %s\n", i+1, vetorLinhas[i]);   //exibe-o na tela
        }
```

Depois disso vc poderia chamar qualquer posição diretamente como o próprio exemplo já demonstra (usando `vetorLinhas[i]`)

Entendeu?

Qualquer coisa é só ir nos comentários!

Comment: Claro que no método leExibeArquivo vc usaria o split normal como está fazendo para ignorar os ;

Comment: Obrigada pela solução :)